# Difference between two approaches to removing items from a linked list?

Tags: rust

I am working on a [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements/), in Rust, which asks for a program that removes elements from a linked list when the contained value is equal to a certain input value (the `val` parameter in the function below).

What is the difference between my approach, which fails to compile, and the second approach, which compiles and passes the test cases for this problem? How can the first program be made to compile? Conceptually, both programs look to be trying to do the same thing, but there appears to be something different about the borrow semantics in the first program.

**Program 1 - Fails to Compile**

```
pub fn remove_elements(
    mut head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, val: i32
) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {        
    let mut current = &mut head;
    while let Some(node) = current {
        if node.val == val {
            *current = node.next.take();
        } else {
            current = &mut node.next;
        }
    }
    head
}
```

Compilation error:

```
Line 35, Char 19: cannot use `*current` because it was mutably borrowed (solution.rs)
   |
35 |         while let Some(node) = current {
   |                   ^^^^^----^
   |                   |    |
   |                   |    borrow of `current.0` occurs here
   |                   use of borrowed `current.0`
   |                   borrow later used here
Line 35, Char 24: cannot borrow `current.0` as mutable more than once at a time (solution.rs)
   |
35 |         while let Some(node) = current {
   |                        ^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
Line 37, Char 17: cannot assign to `*current` because it is borrowed (solution.rs)
   |
35 |         while let Some(node) = current {
   |                        ---- borrow of `*current` occurs here
36 |             if node.val == val {
37 |                 *current = node.next.take();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 assignment to borrowed `*current` occurs here
   |                 borrow later used here
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

**Program 2**

```
pub fn remove_elements(
    mut head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, val: i32
) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut current = &mut head;
    loop {
        match current {
            None => break,
            Some(node) if node.val == val => {
                *current = node.next.take();
            },
            Some(node) => {
                current = &mut node.next;
            }
        }
    }
    head
}
```

For completeness, the `ListNode` is defined as:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}
 
impl ListNode {
    #[inline]
    fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode {
            next: None,
            val
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've found a bug in the borrow checker. This is a failure of `rustc` to live up to the “sufficiently intelligent compiler” standard.

Comment: Thanks! I've submitted an issue to the `rust-lang/rust` repository about this potential bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80161.